# Компиляция крупных Java проектов IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, компиляция

Как компилируются большие, коммерческие  проекты, написанные на Java?

Где-то слышал, что в JAR файл никто не собирает, а каким-то образом компилируют классы и запускают по отдельности. На данный момент использую Gradle с такими настройками. После чего на сервере выполняю команду `java -jar file.jar`. Но меня интересуют единственный ли это вариант:

```
task fJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': "" }
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: "Где-то слышал, что в JAR файл никто не собирает" - вранье

Comment: *Как компилируются большие, коммерческие проекты, написанные на Java?* - молча, стиснув зубы...